# Is there a way I can merge two facebook apps into one?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So basically we were using two separate facebook apps for Mobile apps and desktop due to legacy reasons. We are primarily using it for login.

Now that we have started fetching user friends, the problem we are facing is, facebook only gives you friends who have logged in into the same facebook app which the current user is in. But ideally we would like to connect people whether they have logged in through desktop or mobile app.

Is there anyway we can merge two facebook apps together?

Comment: One thought I have would be to expose your Graph API services in the cloud via REST (or something similar).  Then both mobile and desktop applications can use the same entry point.

Comment: Yea moving forward, thats the plan. To make a common entry point for everyone via APIs. But for existing users, if there is no way to merge the data, then all we can do is hope that those users login again in the new common system.

Comment: There's no way to merge two apps that I know of. I highly doubt that it's possible, because the user access tokens are different by app.

Comment: Correct, you can not “merge” two apps. But you can make both “versions” use the same app id. But users that did not use that app before will have to login and grant permissions to the “new” app again. And the user ids for those users will be different. (If you want to be able to still “recognize” the users that used app A before in app B, you need to connect them to a business first.)